# ExtJS cannot decode JSON message

Tags: c#, javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS to make an Ajax request to server-side, and then I would like to parse the JSON response and do something with it.

The problem is the i can't decode the response text:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: 'Applications/GetFarmCounters.aspx',
                                    params: { farm: 'test', farmid: Ext.getCmp('farm_id').getValue() },
                                    success: function (result, request) {
                                        // result.responseText is here : {succes : true, message : 'test'}

                                        var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);

                                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Decode of stringData OK<br />jsonData.message= ' + jsonData.message);

                                    },
                                    failure: function (response, opts) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Warning', 'Error!');
                                    }
                                });
```

But instead of seing the "test" message in an alert box, i get this error message in Chrome developer tools : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s"

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the json that you are being returned? It definitely looks like it has some problems in it.

Comment: Hi! It's in a comment within the code : {succes : true, message : 'test'}

Comment: JSON needs the properties to be in quotes. so `{"success": true, "message": "test"}` will probably fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a JSON issue

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "test"
}
```

should be the JSON you return. Always test your JSON using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: I've changed it this way, but i still get an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Ext.util.JSON.decode
panel.Ext.form.FormPanel.items.items.listeners.change.Ext.Ajax.request.success
Ext.data.Connection.Ext.extend.onComplete
Ext.data.Connection.Ext.extend.onStateChange

Comment: @maephisto - then I am at a loss. I've tried parsing the JSON as shown above, and it works fine

Comment: `Unexpected token <` is telling me that you are not getting back the JSON you think you are. Visit your URL in the browser (or use curl) and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this know issue.
Check [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?72855-solved-ASP.NET-MVC-Json-parser-problem-!), if it solves your problem